# How to search the entire system (Linux) for a particular string?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find this string:

```
7z a -p
```

I've tried:

grep -iR "7z a -p" /

But it seems to hang after a while, with lots of:

```
grep: /sys/class/vc/vcs5/power/autosuspend_delay_ms: Input/output error
grep: warning: /sys/class/vc/vcsa5/subsystem: recursive directory loop
grep: /sys/class/vc/vcsa5/power/autosuspend_delay_ms: Input/output error
grep: warning: /sys/class/vc/vcs6/subsystem: recursive directory loop
```

EDIT - However, this seems to just look at static text files.  In addition, what about runtime areas, memory and processes? ie the entire system? eg for mysql:

```
ps aux | grep "mysql -u user -p"
```

shows :

```
38164  4292 pts/0    S+   13:16   0:00 mysql -uodbcuser -px xxxxxxxx
```

Interestingly ps aux does hide the password with xxxxx.  I can try with 7zip but it's quite fast, it has to be running at the same time as you run the ps aux command to "catch it.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to guarantee that the "7z a -p$password" is not stored on the server.  Hence I need to demonstrate some tests that show this.

Answer (score 8):

You should exclude directories like `/sys/`, `/proc/` and `/dev/` from your command:

```
grep -iR --exclude-dir='/sys' --exclude-dir='/proc' --exclude-dir='/dev' "7z a -p" /
```

Comment: Thanks, what about runtime processes/memory?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, that string is in a script file. You might try [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/) (aka `ack-grep`).

It will automatically select only script and source files, but you can have it search all files with the `-a` option (in version 1). In version 2, all non-binary files are searched by default.

You can specify directories to ignore or for the search to focus on or ignore particular file types.

```
--[no]ignore-dir=name
--[no]elisp        .el
--[no]erlang       .erl .hrl
--[no]fortran      .f .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .for .ftn .fpp
for a few examples
```

There are many options that are the same as those of GNU `grep` so they will be familiar.

The builtin filtering system is very powerful and configurable. Because of the filtering, searches can be significantly faster than those using `grep`.

[Installation](http://beyondgrep.com/install/) couldn't be simpler.

[documentation](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/)

Comment: Hi Dennis, Please check the update to the question. I hope you can answer it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could throe away errors with

grep -iR "7z a -p" / 2>/dev/null